# When to use private and shared variables for OpenMP

Tags: c, openmp

I was going under the assumption that if you had a nested loop that you wanted to use OpenMP with, that you had to make looping variables for the inner loops private, as shown below.

```
int x,y,z;
#pragma omp parallel for private(y,z)
for (x=0;x<100;x++)
{
    for (y=0;y<100;y++)
    {
        for (z=0;z<100;z++)
        {
             a[x+y+z]=a[x]+a[y]+a[z]; //arbitrary code, a is just an arbitrary array
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run the same loop without the `private(y,z)`, it still runs fine. So what are actually the situations where you need to use `private`/`shared`?

Answer (score 8):

It is important to understand the difference between shared and private, and you seem to do that well. The next thing to learn is that variables declared outside of a parallel region are implicitly `shared` and variables declared inside are implicitly `private`. This makes perfect sense if you think about it and that way you can and should save yourself the explicit declaration by always **declaring variables as locally as possible**.

In your code this means:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(y,z)
for (int x=0;x<100;x++)
{
    for (int y=0;y<100;y++)
    {
        for (int z=0;z<100;z++)
        {
             a[x+y+z]=a[x]+a[y]+a[z]; //arbitrary code, a is just an arbitrary array
        }
    }
}
```

This makes reasoning about your code much easier - with and without OpenMP. For OpenMP it means that code is correct<sup>1</sup> by default. (`a` is implicitly `shared` and `x,z,y` are implicitly `private`)

Explicit data-sharing clauses create redundancy and can also be dangerous unless you know exactly what you are doing: private variables are uninitialized even if they had a valid value outside of the parallel region and what does it even mean to use a private variable after the parallel region? Therefore I strongly recommend the implicit default approach unless necessary for advanced usage.

<sup>1</sup> Your code is actually wrong because multiple threads write different values to the same memory location - and even read from them at the same time. But I'm not going to detail because you mentioned it's an example. Nevertheless shared is most likely what you want for such a loop.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `a[x+y+z]=a[x]+a[y]+a[z];` will not show you any problem, because it happens to be very robust exactly against the kind of potential errors you are looking for.
Try a calculation which is unique to each array eleement written to and writes each array element only once.
E.g. take smaller array, size 1000, loop 0-9, calculate index x+10*y+100*y and write index to value.
Then experiment to provoke errors, e.g. swap x,y,z in calculation.
You will notice that the result is not clean, among other things because y and z get shared. Some array elements will not be written (initialise them to e.g. 1111 to notice) and some will not be written their index.
Maybe write a checker, verifying that index and value are identical for each entry afterwards.

Comment: Even if the result is correct race conditions general kill performance and since performance is the reason for OpenMP it's a very bad idea to have race conditions. In other words, OpenMP should give both the same result (or acceptable result e.g. in the case of floating point arithmetic) and improve performance but not only one of those two.

Comment: @Zboson I don't get your point. I totally agree with what you wrote, but is there some change to my answer which you implicitly want to recommend? Guessing I think you might have misunderstood me and think that I recommend experimenting, finding something which has the correct result and then use that code. That is not what I recommend. I think it is clear that OP already is aware of the correct solution, using explicit `private`. Should I somehow clarify that?

Comment: Although you have a potential race condition on y and z, it need not materialize when they are optimized to register variables (which are private in effect).

Comment: With y and z effectively private, a race condition on a[] might not materialize,  at the expense of every store in the first thread producing a cache eviction,  assuming all threads run on a shared cache.